# nginx serving static files doesn't work properly with comma character

Tags: nginx, static-files

**Summary:** Static files are publishing in **/path/to/root** , If the request is not in the static folders, the request sending **@a1** location block.

**Static files;**

/path/to/root/folder/folder1,111/index.html

/path/to/root/folder/folder1-111/index.html

#### Configuration

```
location / {
   root /path/to/root;
   error_page 418 = @a1;

if ($request_uri ~ .*.sort.*) { return 418; }

   try_files $request_uri $request_uri/index.html $uri.html @a1;
   add_header X-debug-static-1 "$request_uri" always;
}

location @a1 {
    add_header X-debug-web "$request_uri" always;
    include web.conf;
   }
```

**Note:** web.conf going to app

### static serving doesn't work, because folder name have "," character

> curl -I https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 14:56:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 111
Connection: keep-alive
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Location: folder/folder1,111
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
X-debug-web: https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111
```

### static serving works, because folder name doesn't have "," character

> curl -I https://www.example.com/folder/folder1-111

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 15:04:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 306730
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 15:04:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "5a201de9-4ae2a"
X-debug-static-1: /folder/folder1-111
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

**Q-1** https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111 Why this request still going to **@a1** location? Whereas the folder in path/to/root. So, how can I publish folders with commas in filenames from static files?

**Q-2** How can I send request_uri to **@a1** if the **query_string** contains some words?

**Example;**

**words:** sort,q,page

If the **request_uri** have any words from the above, send to **@a1**. If not, publish to the from static files.

Comment: Don't use `$request_uri` with `try_files`, use `$uri` instead. The latter is normalised, URL encoded characters are decoded and the query string has been stripped off. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: Actually I think this isn't about $uri or $request_uri. I did **location ^~ /** and https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111 works.

Comment: BTW, only index.html serving but not index.js with this configuration. https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111/index.html is works but https://www.example.com/folder/folder1,111/index.js isn't working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have found answers of my questions. Latest and working configuration as below.

```
    location ^~ / {
    root /path/to/root;    
    error_page 418 = @a1;

    if ($request_uri ~ "(.*)(some|word)(.*)") { return 418; }

        try_files $request_uri $request_uri/index.html $uri.html @a1;   
     add_header X-debug-static-1 "$request_uri" always; }

     location @a1 {
         add_header X-debug-web "$request_uri" always;
         include web.conf;    }
```